# Accessing values in response of http request without getting error?

Tags: angular, typescript

The results.session_id has a red squiggly on it because it is an unknown parameter. How do I let Angular/TS that it is a valid parameter?

````
```
this.requestManager.loginRequest(email, password).subscribe(
  result => {
    localStorage.setItem('session_id', result.session_id)
    this.router.navigate(['/discover'])
  },
  error => {},
  () => {}
)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access the property:

```
this.requestManager.loginRequest(email, password).subscribe(
  result => {
    localStorage.setItem('session_id', result['session_id'])
    this.router.navigate(['/discover'])
  },
  error => {},
  () => {}
)
```

Otherwise the better option could be creating an interface to represent the “result” and use HttpClient get() with a type in your service:

```
interface Session {
  session_id: string;
}

this.http.get<Session>(“some-url”);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.